# Read ppm P6 image, store into an array and print the array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, ppm

I'm pretty new to programming so excuse my ignorance. I've been trying to store a ppm file into an array and then print whatever i have stored. I am expecting to see numbers from 0 to 255. I don't even know if that's possible, 
but when I print my array what I get is random numbers like this:

i is 0; value is 32
i is 1; value is -101 
i is 2; value is 82 
i is 3; value is 78 
i is 4; value is -77 etc.

All I wanna do actually is to make sure that I've stored the right things into my array in order to change it then properly. So if there's any other way to do this, and my way is not right, it would be very helpful to know.

This is my code:

```
        float * ReadPPM(const char * filename, int * w, int * h) {
        ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open(filename,  ios::binary);
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            int i = 0;
            cout << "File successfully open" << endl;
            myfile.ignore(2, ' ');
            int width;
            int height;
            myfile >> width;
            myfile >> height;
            myfile.ignore(4, ' ');

            w = & width;
            h = & height;

            cout << width << endl;
            cout << height << endl;
            int size = width*height * 3;
        char * buffer = new char[size];
            myfile.read(buffer, size);



            while (i < 500) {
                cout << "i is " << i << "; value is " << (float)(buffer[i]) << endl;
                i++;
            }



            delete[] buffer;
            system("PAUSE");
```

I actually have to store these into a float array, but I used char for now because I believe it is more understandable for me.

Comment: one problem is that `char` signedness is implementation defined. Use `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: Ok I tried but then I cant use read for unsigned.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `ifstream`. Maybe you can cast it to `char *`, like `myfile.read((char*)buffer, size);`. Or maybe use some other solution for reading (like the old `FILE *` way). Or maybe use `basic_ifstream<unsigned char>`?

Comment: this works, thank you! I don't even know why it works though.